# SQL Group Function

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to get count of three columns by using SUM(), when I execute the query, it says '#1111 - Invalid use of group function'. I tried correcting the group functions, even though it shows the error.

I need the perfect count of columns 2,3,4

```
SELECT c.name, 

    SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct cmc.id) = COUNT(distinct ccc.id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "COND1",
    SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct cmc.id) > 0 AND COUNT(distinct cmc.id) != COUNT(distinct ccc.id) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) AS "COND2",
    SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct cmc.id) = 0 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) AS "COND3"

    FROM
    lesson_modules_completion cmc
    INNER JOIN lesson_modules cm ON cmc.lessonmoduleid = cm.id
    INNER JOIN lesson_completion_settings ccc ON cm.lesson = ccc.lesson 
    INNER JOIN lesson c ON cm.lesson = c.id
    INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = cmc.userid
    WHERE ccc.criteriatype=4
    GROUP BY c.name
```

I need the count of each user has Completed modules, Inprocess modules and Notstarted modules for each course, where getting the count of userids from table CC by taking courseia from table CM, get number of modules that an user has completed from each course.

(A course can have morethan one module and a course can have number of users attempted all modules, few modules or not attempted at all).

So, I need number of users - has done number of modules - in a course. (3 logics)

(COND1 i.e.,Completed.Users ) : If number of modules attempted is equal to number of modinstance from table CMS (ex: no. of modules attempted by a user per course= 9, no.modinstance = 9. Because 7 is not equal to 9, They are completed.)

(COND2 i.e.,Inprocess.Users ) : Number of modules attempted should be >0, but not equal to [count(modinstance) per course] (ex: no. of modules attempted by a user per course= 7 , no.modinstance = 9. Because 7 is not equal to 9, They are Inprocess.)

(COND2 i.e.,Nostart.Users ) : Number of modules attempted should be equal to 0, (ex: no. of modules attempted by a user per course= 0. They are Notstarted).

You can refer my query, It was all doing good, but I need the count of COND1, COND2, COND3

I need the OUTPUT :

```
 lesson        COND1              COND2                  COND3
 5              65                 32                       6
 6              40                 12                       15
 8              43                 56                       0
 9               0                 7                        9
```

Comment: You need to specify the columns in your `CASE` statements in the `GROUP BY` clause. Either that, or change your query.

Comment: COUNT function inside SUM function is the issue. You need to rewrite the code as per your requirement or explain your requirement mentioning data pattern and expected output.

Comment: Seahawk - I had edited the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select lesson,sum(COND1) as COND1, sum(COND2) as COND2,sum(COND3) as COND3
from
(
SELECT c.name, 
       ccc.lesson,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct cmc.id) = COUNT(distinct ccc.id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "COND1",
    CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct cmc.id) > 0 AND COUNT(distinct cmc.id) != COUNT(distinct ccc.id) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END AS "COND2",
    CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct cmc.id) = 0 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END AS "COND3"

    FROM
    lesson_modules_completion cmc
    INNER JOIN lesson_modules cm ON cmc.lessonmoduleid = cm.id
    INNER JOIN lesson_completion_settings ccc ON cm.lesson = ccc.lesson 
    INNER JOIN lesson c ON cm.lesson = c.id
    INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = cmc.userid
    WHERE ccc.criteriatype=4
    GROUP BY c.name,ccc.lesson
) t
group by lesson
```

Comment: Dark Knight -- Can you give an example from my edited question

Comment: please create an SQL Fiddle with your data. That will allow me to help.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fb71/1   -    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3df9   -  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38934  -  I had created 3 schema's for 3 different tables. From these 3 tables, I have  frame a query as looks like my query

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? what is the logic behind the output?

Comment: I had explained in the question. Can you please check.

Comment: There is no c.lesson at all in the query. It says Unknown column 'c.lesson' &  in 'field list' Can you check the query

Comment: I updated query..Can you try now? Mark as answer if this answers your question.

Comment: Now the query works, but I asked the count of COND1, COND2, COND3. It was showing a wrong count of these three. I guess you have to go with users combination

Comment: that is strage.. it should give the right result.. check if you need to slightly modify the condition.. but this should mostly work.

Comment: GROUP BY c.name,ccc.lesson are both same. If I give GROUP BY cmc.userid

Comment: I thought c.name is username. try `group by cmc.userid,ccc.lesson`

Comment: Could we add group by cmc.userid some where, as because COND3 is showing a wrong double count because of this. And If I remove group by cmc.userid, COND3 is working fine and COND1 is showing a wrong count. This group by cmc.userid can be used only for COND1 and COND2, but not COND3. Are there any possibilities like this